# How to fetch data using id in JSON ionic3

Tags: json, ionic-framework

I am creating a News Reader application using JSON. If I click the item in the list view, Details page is open. In that Details page image, title, and paragraph is placed on that page, as an item in the list view. I got doubt about that 1. If I clicked the item that image, title, and paragraph pass to the other page 2. Pass only id details page using id fetch the image, header, and paragraph help me to solve this

[image: I created Sample app]

Answer (score 0):

You can user Navparams

Example

home.ts

```
    goToDetail(item){
    this.navCtrl.push(ProductPage, { item: item });
    console.log(ProductPage, { item: item });
}
```

home.html (give click function)

```
(click)="goToDetail(item)"
```

and you can use code

```
      this.item = this.navParams.get("item");
```

in bottom constructor

Comment: Please use comments for asking questions. Wait for the comment privilege at 50 to do so. Please improve the rest of your answer by providing the essential parts directly, i.e. not as link.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.